# How to Pin a Class to memory which contains a SqlConnection Object

Tags: c#, sql-server

How can a class instance which contains a `SqlConnection` object be "pinned" in memory. So that I can recreate another `SqlConnection` object from the `IntPtr` of that instance, so that recreated `SqlConnection` also points to the same `SqlConnection` object. So that it would give success if we check with

```
bool success = object.ReferenceEquals(conn, conn2);
```

I have tried this code given here by even giving the `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` attribute as I read somewhere that this attribute is required for the class object to get pinned.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]  
public sealed class MyConnection
{
    private SqlConnection _con = null;

    public MyConnection(string oSqlServer,
        string oDatabase,
        string oUser,
        string oPassword,
        int oTimeOut = 20)
    {
        string connectionString = "Server=" + oSqlServer + ";" + "Database=" + oDatabase + ";" + "User=" + oUser + ";" + "Password=" + oPassword + ";" + "Trusted_Connection=false" + ";" + "Connection Timeout=" + oTimeOut + ";" + "Persist Security Info=False";
        _con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public void Open()
    {
        _con.Open();
    }
}
```

And I call it using these lines

```
MyConnection conn = new MyConnection("SqlServer2014", "Database1", "User1", "Password1", 11);
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(conn, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr ip = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
```

Then use the same `IntPtr` value to do this and get the `SqlConnection` object back again.

```
MyConnection conn2 = (GCHandle.FromIntPtr(ip).Target as MyConnection);
```

So that both conn and conn2 basically point to the same object in memory,
so that this should give true

```
bool success = object.ReferenceEquals(conn, conn2);
```

The class should get pinned. But I get an error

> Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data.

probably because of SqlConnection object. But then If we do not want the `SqlConnection` instance in the heap memory to change location because I am taking the `AddrOfPinnedObject()` so that I can get a GCHandle using the same `IntPtr` and recreate another `SqlConnection` object which POINTS TO THE SAME `SqlConnection` already in memory, so that both the connections point to the same object in memory.

Comment: Pinning `MyConnection` won't pin the `SqlConnection`... This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Why are you trying this? As far as I know each connection which inherits from DbConnection has to be created/disposed every time it is used, because in the background is a connection (pool) manager.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? SqlConnection implements a connection pool, you should strive to keep it as short lived as possible.

Comment: Whatever you *think* you can achieve with this, this is not the right way to go. Do not reuse `SqlConnection` objects across scopes and don't do funny things with keeping disposable objects pinned. At best you could share *connection strings* so you can "recreate" connections. `SqlConnection` is itself already nothing more than a handle to a pooled connection object; it should not be treated as a shared resource.

Comment: Pretty unclear why you think this is useful.  But there's just no need to pin the object to generate an IntPtr.  Use GCHandle.ToIntPtr() instead.  You can then, later, use FromIntPtr() to get the GCHandle back, whose Target property gets you the object reference back.  Don't forget Free().

Comment: Or, y'know, change the code being called so it accepts an `SqlConnection` or `object`, switch from CodeDom to `Reflection.Emit`/expression trees, or even just open a new connection anyway because it's actually not that expensive? Failing that, you could expose a static `Dictionary` property mapping some string key of your choosing (say, a GUID) to an `SqlConnection`, and have the other code get at that property with reflection (using well-known assembly/class names). While still incredibly clumsy, it avoids pinning and serializing object handles, which is even worse.

Comment: @hans you mean i should use GCHandle.Alloc() without the Pinned. But then GC could move the location even within seconds and the IntPtr from where i will recreate the object/target would not be the same. Either that IntPtr location could have no object at all and my GCHandle.FromIntPtr() will either crash or may have some other object there

Comment: Yes.  Doesn't matter that it gets moved since there is only *one* object, the GCHandle.Target property changes as well.  The IntPtr identifies the GCHandle, not the object.  It doesn't move, somewhat obvious from it being a struct and not a class.

Comment: @Hans you are a darling. it worked great (and you got my concepts also cleared)

Comment: @jeroen thanks for your comments also. Surely connection object should be kept open for the shortest amount of time and not use them as shared resources.